# How to deselect items in recycler view and validate it?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am beginner in Android Kotlin , I am developing app which requires a selected data from recycler view to be in an arraylist. selection work fine ,if i selected item it will validate the value is null or not. if value not null button will enable. the problem is when i unselected item, the button is still enable and item still not removed from the selected data arrayList(data from API). if someone could help me to solve the issue, will be very glad. Thanks a lot. here is my code

```
    private var checkPosition = -1

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): GridViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_pul, parent, false)
        return GridViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: GridViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindPul(listPul[position], listener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listpul.size
    }

    inner class GridViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        fun bindPul(pul: Model, listener: OnItemClickListener) = with(itemView){
            val binding = ItemPBinding.bind(itemView)
            binding.lblPayAmount.text = p.ModelValue.toDouble().currencyFormatter()
            when (checkPosition) {-1 -> {
                    binding.itemPul.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
                    binding.itemPul.strokeColor = Color.parseColor("#DDEBF9")
                    binding.lblCheck.setVisible(false)
                }else -> when(checkPosition){
                    absoluteAdapterPosition -> {
                        binding.itemPul.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F5FAFF"))
                        binding.itemPul.strokeColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
                        binding.lblCheck.setVisible(true)
                    }else -> {
                        binding.itemP.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
                        binding.itemP.strokeColor = Color.parseColor("#DDEBF9")
                        binding.lblCheck.setVisible(false)
                    }
                }
            }
            setOnClickListener {
                binding.itemPul.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F5FAFF"))
                binding.itemPul.strokeColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
                binding.lblCheck.setVisible(true)

                if (checkPosition != absoluteAdapterPosition){
                    notifyItemChanged(checkPosition)
                    checkPosition = absoluteAdapterPosition
                }
                else{
                    binding.itemPul.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
                    binding.itemPul.strokeColor = Color.parseColor("#DDEBF9")
                    binding.lblCheck.setVisible(false)
                }
                listener.onItemClick(pul)

            }
        }
    }
    fun updateChecked(item: Model){
        listp.mapIndexed { _, Model ->  Model.isSelected = Model.ModelValue == item.ModelValue}
        notifyItemChanged(checkPosition)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(pul: Model)
    }
}
```